# Stuck with Gitolite on OSX

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion, gitolite

I am in the process of installing the latest version of gitolite on an osx mountain lion server.  I set it up under it's own 'git' user account and followed the instructions here: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

I am getting stuck in trying to check-out the gitolite-admin repo from the server on my workstation.  I run this command:

```
git clone git@gitserver:gitolite-admin
```

but get this in return:

```
Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
Connection closed by gitserver
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It seems that I got the SSH set-up correctly because it's not asking for a PWD but I am stuck on where to look to try to debug the problem.

Thanks,
Grant

---

result from ssh -v

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitserver [gitserver] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xxxxx
debug1: Host 'gitserver' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
Connection closed by gitserver
```

Looks OK here unless I am missing some detail.

Comment: Take the user@hostname section and argue it to ssh with the verbose switch: `ssh -v git@gitserver`. Many git problems are actually SSH problems. If your SSH connection works fine, then you can start worrying about git/gitolite

Comment: Wanted to add that this is a fresh install on a new machine that has never had it installed before.

Comment: Ben, Thanks for the suggestion.  It seemed to work fine with no errors.  I can already login to the machine via ssh.

Comment: I did see you said SSH was working, but worth checking :) The number of times it's tripped me up...! From memory, I had issues when I used the same key for gitolite admin and general SSH access to the box gitolite was running on. Hazy memories but I believe this was simply bypassing gitolite. I'd check you don't have an issue along those lines. Next debugging step would be to just clone the admin repo with a local path to see if that works. There is that and some other suggestions here if you haven't seen them: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#lost-key

Comment: I looked at them but did not try them all.  I just tried the 'going around gitolite' and was able to checkout and updated the config to include a few more user names.  I was able to push it back using 'gitolite push' too.  Hmmm....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue configuring a bare git repo in mountain lion. I uncommented the following lines of `/etc/sshd_config`:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

The last one was related to the missing PATH error in .ssh/environment, but the first one was the one that allowed connections from ie. msysgit.

PS (*edit*): In the case of msysgit, I also setup the SSH agent (`eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add`) with OpenSSH key imported in pageant (as my `GIT_SSH=path_to_plink`). That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On osx server, at least since 2015, also enable ssh access explicitly for the repository owner. In my case I have my server configured to allow only a few users. This caused very similar problems like you had.